# How to replace exact string in shell?

Tags: shell, unix

I just want to replace an exact string in shell.

```
str="My name is Sourav. My user name is Souravc. Sourav and Souravc is great person"

to_be_rplace="Sourav"

rplace_with=67776
```

ouput have to be:

```
new_str="My name is 67776. My user name is Souravc. 67776 and Souravc is great person"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` to do edit strings

```
echo $str | sed 's/Sourav[. ]/67776/g'
```

Here the sed command will find and replace the string `$to_be_rplace` with `$rplace_with`.

`[. ]` is used so that only the to_be_replaced string ending with `.` or  space is only replaced.

Comment: If you meant for `$to_be_rplace` and `$rplace_with` to be variables then note that they won't be expanded within single quotes.

Comment: any better solution?
as [. ] might not work because str will also be a variable. Any String can appear there

Answer (score 0):

Use `\< pattern \>`

```
$ sed 's/\<Sourav\>/67776/g' file
$ echo "My name is Sourav. My user name is Souravc. Sourav and Souravc is great person" | sed 's/\<Sourav\>/67776/g'
My name is 67776. My user name is Souravc. 67776 and Souravc is great person
```

Comment: of course it will. Replace single quotes with double quotes. `sed "s/\<$var\>/replace/g" file`